Issues compiling a simple cpp script using wtsapi32.h
I'm trying to compile the following cpp script on a Windows 10 machine
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Wtsapi32.h>
int main()
{
  return 0;
}

using a MinGW installation with the command
g++ -o executable script.cpp -luser32 -lwtsapi32

I also tried specifying the lib and include explicitly, both
-I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0" -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0"

and
-I"D:\Programme\MinGw\include" -L"D:\Programme\MinGw\lib"

but there appear to be issues linking the header, as I get the error
d:\programme\mingw\include\wtsapi32.h:82:3: error: 'WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS' does not name a type
   82 |   WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS State;

I want to use Wtsapi32.h for a more complex script, that monitors the user login state. This script gives me more of the was not declared in this scope, does not name a type and has not been declared errors.
I'd appreciate any help getting to run this simple script, so I hopefully will be able to run the more complex one too, thanks!

Works for me out of the box on MSYS2 GCC, without any compiler flags. Don't try to use MinGW with MSVC's headers, get a version of MinGW that directly supports headers you need.

The error message indicates that the WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS type is not recognized. This usually means that the necessary headers or definitions are not included or available in your MinGW setup.
Ensure you are using an up-to-date version of MinGW that includes support for Wtsapi32.h.
